# Can I set something so that i my git project don't store the package

Tags: git

i feel it's a file storing the old commits locally, so that i can still have the whole history even the git server is down. But I don't need this feature, my git server is reliable enough. I want to keep every extra things in the server and only the current version in my computers. What should i do?

I am using SourceTree in PC/Mac and Gogs as my server

Comment: Git is a decentralized version control, so no, you cannot really do that. You can make a shallow clone as DavidN's answer suggests, but when you create new commits on that clone all of those will be stored locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this. There is a feature in git clone to limit the number of commits, try `git clone --depth N <repository>`

```
--depth <depth>
Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions.
```

Comment: Also, consider whether you want the origin's default branch (current HEAD) or all branches, with the `[--[no-]single-branch]` option as well.